# Multi-Target Regression Random Forest Theory

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am working on a project that involves predicting multiple continuous outputs and I am using the random forest regressor from sklearn to accomplish this. I feel like I have a pretty good understanding about the underlying theory behind decision trees and random forests for single output regression problems, but I am a little confused as to how the random forest regressor is able to seamlessly extrapolate to multiple outputs. I have read a few papers that talk about adding a covariance matrix to the loss function or using Mahalanobis Distance. Can anyone explain the theory behind multi-target regression in sklearn?